# Is there a topological analogue for this result?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, soft-question, field-theory, integral-domain

From the construction of a field of fractions of a commutative domain, we have the following:

> Let $D$ be a commutative domain and $F$ be its field of fractions. Then every monomorphism of $D$ into a field $K$ has a unique extension to a monomorphism of $F$ into $K$.

This sounds very much like something which has its analogue in topology, so I would like to know if an analogous thing exists in topology and what it is.

Comment: "Topology" is extremely broad and it is very unclear what sort of analogue you have in mind...

Comment: @EricWofsey maybe "metric topology" would be better?

Comment: @EricWofsey I have in mind something like the field of fractions being the completion. I am not sure how much sense this makes. I am happy with anything which may be regarded as an analogue.

Comment: This is an example of an adjoint functor (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/adjoint+functor), specifically the left adjoint to the inclusion of the category of fields into the category of integral domains and injective maps. It is even an example of a particular kind of adjoint called a reflector (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/reflective+subcategory), which includes various kinds of completions as special cases, including metric completion and Stone-Cech compactification.

Answer (score 2):

You mean like the [Stone-Čech compactification](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification) of a space? Every continuous function of the space into a compact Hausdorff space extends to one on the entire compactification.

There are lots of examples like this: you should look up more examples of universal properties.

Comment: Yes, "universal (mapping) properties" would be the phrase to search on. Such characterizations exist, and are useful (even if under-used) throughout mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

In metric spaces there is a notion of completion: if $(X,d)$ is a metric space, there is a complete metric space $(Y, d')$ such that

- there is an isometry $i$ from $(X,d) \to (Y,d')$ such that $i[X]$ is dense in $Y$.
- for any uniformly continuous function $f:(X,d) \to (Z,\rho)$ where the latter is a complete metric space, there is a unique continuous  $f': (Y,d') \to (Z, \rho)$ such that $f' \circ i = f$.

It is a little like adding fractions to a domain, which you do to add inverses that aren't there yet. Here you're adding limits for Cauchy sequences that have no limit yet. Both are characterised by a universal mapping extension property.

As mentioned by @rschwieb compactifications are another example (adding limits for ultrafilters that do not yet converge).